# update multiple values in one column using one sql query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress-database

I am working with huge MySQL database and need to set same two values for one table field.

My table is post3 and set two values 'attachment', 'image/jpeg' for post_type column.

I have tried following queries

```
UPDATE `post3`
SET post_type = ''
WHERE post_type IN ('attachment', 'image/jpeg');
```

The code is executed however, doesn't affect rows and getting following results

```
0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0038 seconds.)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What about if you try `WHERE post_type = "attachment" OR post_type = "image/jpeg" does it work? As well when you do a SELECT with the conditional you are using, Does it returns something? What does it return?

Comment: I'm tried with `WHERE post_type = "attachment" OR post_type = "image/jpeg" and it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to be working for me. If it is not, I would suspect that you simply don't have data that matches this criteria. Can you show us? See my response with fiddle to see what I mean.

Comment: @Binod Bhattarai that's weird, as well doing a `SELECT COUNT(*)` from the items that have post_type like your conditional returns something greater than 0? Does your column contains exactly "attachment" or "image/jpeg" ? Or that is part of a string?

Answer (score 0):

For me this type of logic works fine, here is a fiddle showing it. Included an select before and after so that you can see that the change is done. In this case, I would assume that your table post3 simply does not have any post_type called 'attachment' or 'image/jpeg'. If so, please show us an select * from post3 with these shown.
This works from MySQL v5.5 -> v8.0, at the very least.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xaEyFGU7xmhTk569MePY91/2

```
CREATE TABLE post3(
    id int,
    post_type  varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO post3 (id, post_type) VALUES(1,'attachment');
INSERT INTO post3 (id, post_type) VALUES(2,'attachment');
INSERT INTO post3 (id, post_type) VALUES(3,'image/jpeg');
INSERT INTO post3 (id, post_type) VALUES(4,'image/jpeg');

select *
from `post3`;

UPDATE `post3`
SET post_type = ''
WHERE post_type IN ('attachment', 'image/jpeg');

select *
from `post3`;
```

First select:

| id | post_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | attachment |
| 2 | attachment |
| 3 | image/jpeg |
| 4 | image/jpeg |

*Update query ran*

Second select:

| id | post_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |